# Time complexity of Latent dirichlet Allocation

Tags: nlp, lda, topic-modeling

What is the computational complexity of Latent Dirichlet Allocation in terms of the number of documents (D), topics (T), average length of documents (L), and words (W)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on your memory. LDA adapts a probabilistic approach that calculates the probability of the topic. Your memory performs the computations. If you have infinite memory, the computational complexity is zero.

Answer (score 0):

It should be O(DLT).
There are three for loops in the algorithm which are:
for d in D:
  for w in L:
    for t in T:
      calculate the probability of assigning w to t.

Answer (score 0):

"If you have infinite memory, the computational complexity is zero." Alas, if only this were true. You also need infinite physical dimensions to communicate between the memory items in constant time.